# How to launch terminal session and run on launch. macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, launchd

I want to launch two terminal sessions and run a command in each on launch in macOS.
I want the graphical terminal to launch, I'm not after a launchagent that runs in the background.
Is this possible?
Thank you!

Comment: have you tried `Automator` an app that is preinstalled on all macs?

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended function of window groups in terminal app.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/use-window-groups-trml15652/mac